# How to add two Strings, string having TimeIntervals?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nstimeinterval

I have two strings with time interval data. I want to add that two time intervals and store into another string. This is my data

```
NSString *oldTime=@"00:24";         //Time format is "mm:ss"


NSString *newTime=@"00:07";         //Time format is "mm:ss"
```

After adding two strings i need to store that total time in another string like below

```
NSString *totalTime=oldTime+newTime;        //(totalTime=00:31)
```

I am fresher to iOS so please send me the code for this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: U need to work on logics. Develop your logic by practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know this is perfect solution. But this will work

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];

    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:@"00:00"];
    NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"00:24"];
    NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"00:07"];

    NSTimeInterval interval1 = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date];
    NSTimeInterval interval2 = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date];

    NSDate *addedDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval1+interval2];

    NSString *resultDate = [df stringFromDate:addedDate];
```

Hope this helps.